# imagefilter to create CSS sprites

Tags: php, gd, imagefilter

I'd like to automate creation of images for CSS sprites.

My goal is to convert a color thumbnail into black and white and merge it into one image with a color one on top and black at the bottom).

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$image = imagecreatefrompng('test.png');

if($image && imagefilter($image , IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE))
{
    echo 'Image converted.';

    imagepng($image, 'test.png');
}
else
{
    echo 'Conversion failed.';
}

imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

Comment: what doyou mean by "merge". is this an overlay with blending, or is this like making the top part of the image a color version, while the bottom half is a black and white version. any more details?

Comment: I would like the 'merged' images to be made of the color (top) and black & white (bottom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$image_path = 'test.png';
$input_image = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
$image_info = getimagesize($image_path);
$output_image = imagecreatetruecolor($image_info[0], $image_info[1] * 2);
imagecopy ($output_image, $input_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $image_info[0], $image_info[1]);
if(imagefilter($input_image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE)) {
    echo 'Image converted.';
    imagecopy ($output_image, $input_image, 0, $image_info[1], 0, 0, $image_info[0], $image_info[1]);
    imagepng($output_image, 'test.png');
} else {
    echo 'Conversion failed.';
}
imagedestroy($input_image);
imagedestroy($output_image);
?>
```

Comment: creates new image that is twice the height of the original, then copies a color version to the top, and a greyscale version to the bottom, then resaves over original image file with new image.

Comment: I am getting: Fatal error: Call to undefined function createimagetruecolor() I changed it to imagecreatetruecolor and the conversion fails.

Comment: oops, should be imagecreatetruecolor() instead. sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug ($image1 should be $output_image)

```
<?php
$image_path = 'test.png';
$input_image = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
$image_info = getimagesize($image_path);
$output_image = imagecreatetruecolor($image_info[0], $image_info[1] * 2);
imagecopy ($output_image, $input_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $image_info[0], $image_info[1]);
if($output_image && imagefilter($output_image , IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE)) {
    echo 'Image converted.';
    imagecopy ($output_image, $input_image, 0, $image_info[1], 0, 0, $image_info[0], $image_info[1]);
    imagepng($output_image, 'test.png');
} else {
    echo 'Conversion failed.';
}
imagedestroy($input_image);
imagedestroy($output_image);
?>
```

Comment: Or input image, depending which you want on top. I originally intended to filter the input image. Edited post.